# Flutter Web And Firebase Analytics Integration Problem

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics

I implemented Firebase Analytics implementation to my Flutter Web project as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=flutter)
I can see my application on Firebase Console but I couldn't see any traffic referrer data or Campaigns section in Acquisition to track my ad performances.

In old questions and answers, they suggested adding JS code to index.html but the official document doesn't tell anything about this.

What should I do to implement Google Analytics fully functional to my Flutter Web project?